# Jsoup and Method calls

Tags: java, android, methods, jsoup

A simple question hopefully, go easy i'm a beginner...

When using jsoup for multiple calls to different websites is it better to group the different websites under different Methods?

```
website1();
website2();
website3();
```

or just have them run one after the other under 1 Method..

```
websites();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to use methods? Can't you use separate classes with lets say `handle` method which will return result you want? This way you could wrap your url in specific classes, store them in some collection, iterate over it and invoke `handle` for each wrapper and store/use results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting method is always better :) Code is more readable.

```
login(username, password);
selectProfile();
selectChangePassword();
setNewPassword(password);
logout();
```

This is much more easier to read :)

Comment: Hi, By passing the connection do you mean keeping the connection open the internet open for jsoup instead of closing it after each method?

Comment: No, this is no possible, corrected :) But you can extrad some method as static and reuse.

Comment: Ah, ok :), Thanks for your answer anyway. Will wait awhile before to see if anyone else chips in but i'm sure they will agree with you, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want to organize your data. The more methods the merrier for decomposition and debugging (see printStackTrace()). There are a variety of reasons why decomposition is so useful. Method calls have negligible effects on the speed of your program. Have you considered the following?

```
void websites(){ //I am assuming it returns void.
    website1();
    website2();
    website3();
    website4();
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and stating that, "Method calls have negligible effects on the speed of your program". I did wonder how much difference they make.